# Sum properties array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of objects, for example:

```
 [{
      name: 'mike',
      id: 3312,
      points: 2,
      summary: 'example',
  }, {
      name: 'andrew',
      id: 4123,
      points: 1,
      summary: 'example',
  }, {
      name: 'mike',
      id: 0522,
      points: 5,
      summary: 'example',
  }]
```

I need to sum the points for each person, the problem I´m facing is there are more than 50 different person names so I can´t do something like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
    if (issues[i].name == 'mike') {
        //////////////////////
    }
}
```

Because the API in future can return a `new Person`.

Comment: There are different `id` values. Does this mean the primary key is going to be `name`?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, yes, the ID i get it´s from an Issue ID, it´s different in every object!

Comment: Hi! You seem to have made a good start on it, but you've stopped in the middle. You need to actually sum up the values. Your best bet here is to do that (and any necessary research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, etc.). ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times, so a really thorough search will turn up answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `reduce` into an object indexed by `name`:

```js
const input = [{
   name: 'mike',
   id: 3312,
   points: 2,
   summary: 'example',
},
{
   name: 'andrew',
   id: 4123,
   points: 1, 
   summary: 'example',
},
{
   name: 'mike',
   id: 0522,
   points: 5,
   summary: 'example',
}];
const points = input.reduce((a, { name, points }) => (
  Object.assign(a, { [name]: (a[name] || 0) + points })
), {});
console.log(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `reduce` and keep things simple you can still use a `forEach` loop as below:

```js
const input = [{
   name: 'mike',
   id: 3312,
   points: 2,
   summary: 'example',
},
{
   name: 'andrew',
   id: 4123,
   points: 1, 
   summary: 'example',
},
{
   name: 'mike',
   id: 0522,
   points: 5,
   summary: 'example',
}];

var res = {};

input.forEach((obj) => {
  res[obj.name] = res[obj.name] ? res[obj.name]+obj.points : obj.points;
});


console.log(res);
```